# Why can't I use lapply factor within a function?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame with columns labeled q1, q2, q3, etc. I want to create a function that will take arguments (variable name, data frame, level vector, label vector) and change the coded answers to strings.

For example, if q3 is coded 1, 2, or 3, and I want to change that to "bad", "neutral", "good" AND q4 is a series of 4 columns (q4r1, q4r2, q4r3, q4r4) with coded responses 1, 2, or 3 and I want to change those to "red", "blue", "green":

```
findCol <- function(vn, df) {
  if (length(which(grepl(vn, names(df)))) > 1) {
    which(grepl(vn, names(df)))
  } else {
    which(colnames(df)==vn)
  }
}
```

And

```
labelChng <- function(cv, df, levs, labs) {
  if (length(cv) > 1) {
    df[cv[1]:cv[length(cv)]] <- lapply(df[cv[1]:cv[length(cv)]], factor, 
    levels = levs, labels = labs)
  } else {
    df[cv] <- lapply(df[cv], factor, levels = levs, labels = labs)
  }
}
```

Then

```
q3c <- findCol("q3", myData)
q3lev <- c(1:3)
q3lab <- c("bad", "neutral", "good")
q4c <- findCol("q4", myData)
q4lev <- c(1:3)
q4lab <- c("red", "blue", "green")
```

The findCol function works just fine, but when I try to run labelChng, it doesn't actually change anything.  When I run this directly in the console:

```
myData[q4c[1]:q4c[length(q4c)]] <- lapply(myData[q4c[1]:q4c[length(q4c)]], factor, 
levels = q4lev, labels = q4lab)
```

it works just fine, but not when I use:

```
labelChng(q4c, myData, q4lev, q4lab)
```

I'm new to this so may be missing something obvious. Any feedback helps.

Comment: The first function can be shortened to `findCol <- function(vn, df) which(grepl(vn, names(df)))`?

Comment: I think you're not actually making a change. The `df` you are manipulating in your `labelChng` function is local to that function only. If you want to change something you should use a `return(df)`

Comment: @MikeyMike I was thinking the same thing

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune - yup, you beat me to the answer. You got my vote!

Comment: Ah!  Yes, I need to return.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second function does not return a value and can be simplified:

```
#Simplified Helpers
findCol <- function(vn, df) grepl(vn, names(df))

labelChng <- function(cv, df, levs, labs) {
  df[cv] <- lapply(df[cv], factor, levels=levs, labels=labs)
  return(df)
}

myData <- data.frame(q1=1:3, q2=3:1, q3=2)
myData
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  1  3  2
# 2  2  2  2
# 3  3  1  2


q2c <- findCol('q2', myData)
q2lev <- c(1:3)
q2lab <- c("bad", "neutral", "good")
labelChng(q2c, myData, q2lev, q2lab)
#   q1      q2 q3
# 1  1    good  2
# 2  2 neutral  2
# 3  3     bad  2
```

Comment: Maybe also worth pointing out that the `cv[1]:cv[length(cv)]` is a bad idea. If it ever differs from plain old `cv`, it'll be doing weird things (altering cols that don't meet the grepl criterion).

Comment: Oh I haven't gotten into the shredding yet.

Comment: Yes -- i see the issue with that now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the plyr package.  The plyr library has two useful `revalue` and `mapvalues` functions to covert one set of factors into another.  Here is an example:

```
library(plyr)
df<-data.frame(x=1:3)
df$x<-as.factor(df$x)
q3lev <- c(1:3)
q3lab <- c("bad", "neutral", "good")

df$x<-mapvalues(df$x, from=q3lev, to=q3lab)
```